# Trying to fill login form using JS inside python with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, bots

I'm currently trying to fill username and password information inside a login form for a page called Invictus using JS, the case is that I'm executing such code inside **python** using **selenium** library by using **execute_script()**, the problem stands when I try to dynamically pass the username and the password to the javascript code; Python compiler raises an exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I don't understand why is happening such a problem, the code which seems to be causing the error is the following:

```
username = "myusername@domain.com"

driver.execute_script("""
                document.getElementById('j_username').value = %s;
                document.getElementById('j_password').value = 'password123';
                document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
            """ %username)
```

I'm using samples as the username and password fields for this post, so that's not causing the problem if your idea was such

If any curiosity of which page I'm trying to execute the python code its Invictus.com sneaker seller

Any suggestion or idea would be well received, thanks

Comment: Should the `%s` in the JavaScript string be wrapped in quotes? For example: `.value = '%s';`

Comment: @joncloud not sure about it, it works for a common string, not sure why to use such representation

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one changed the formating.

```
  driver.execute_script("""
            document.getElementById('j_username').value = %s;
            document.getElementById('j_password').value = 'password123';
            document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
        """ ,username)
```

Comment: this does not work, username is not defined in javascript, the error is: javascript error: username is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root cause may be due to the generated JavaScript.

In order to adjust, the `%s` needs to be wrapped in quotes (`'%s'`), otherwise the JavaScript code will attempt to refer to a reference of whatever the value that is held in `username`. For comparison, this should make the generated code the same as the following line that assigns the password.

```py
driver.execute_script("""
                document.getElementById('j_username').value = '%s';
                document.getElementById('j_password').value = 'password123';
                document.getElementById('loginForm').submit();
            """ %username)
```

For additional reference I ran some small samples through the Python Interactive Shell:

```py
>>> "my text value: %s" % "joncloud"
'my text value: joncloud'
>>> "my text value: '%s'" % "joncloud"
"my text value: 'joncloud'"
```